# Lua string.match to extract some values of a HTML

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm using Lua `string.match` to extract some values of a HTML but I'm having some problems with some attributes.

To extract a phone number like this: 0000-0000, I'm using the mask:

```
local value = string.match(STRING, "%d%d%d%d-%d%d%d%d")
```

But Lua is returning something like this: `"0000000"`

Where is the `"-"` in the middle of the mask string?

And is there any way to do something like this:

`"%d[4]-%d[4]"` (specifying how many chars will appear in string)

Comment: To help make the context clear can you also add what `STRING` contains when `string.match` is called?

Comment: Actually string is a HTML after a GET method. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-` is a special control character in [Lua patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1). Since you want the *literal* `-` character, you need to escape it with the `%` character. So use `%-`.

Comment: @hjpotter92: I've been using Regex's for a while, so I forgot Lua's escape character.

Comment: Didn´t work with \- but it works with %-. Thank you very much Nicol and hjpotter!